# C++ Concepts for templated types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Given one has similar types:

```
template<typename T> using a_T = std::unique_ptr<T[]>;
template<typename T> using b_T = std::unique_ptr<a_T<T>>[]>;
template<typename T> using c_T = std::unique_ptr<b_T<T>>[]>;
template<typename T> using d_T = std::unique_ptr<c_T<T>>[]>;
```

Also we define a simple function like:

```
template<typename T> bool is_allocated(T const& ref){
  return (ref == nullptr);
}
```

Which should work for all 4 types.

How to write a C++ concept which checks one of these types is supplied to the function? I can not figure out the correct syntax to define a concept for a templated type.

My attempt is:

```
template<typename T> concept cArrayType = std::is_same_v<AT,a_T<T>> ||
                                          std::is_same_v<AT,b_T<T>> ||
                                          std::is_same_v<AT,c_T<T>> ||
                                          std::is_same_v<AT,d_T<T>>;
```

But, of course, this lacks how to pass `AT<T>` as a type.

Comment: What is `AT` in your concept? Why not simply define your function to accept any `unique_ptr<T[]>` type and do away with the concept?

Comment: The function can simply be `template<typename T> bool is_allocated(std::unique_ptr<T> const& ref)`, but it doesn't really do anything useful anyway, because `std::unique_ptr` can already be explicitly converted to `bool`, so that if you have a unique ptr named `ptr` you can usually simply write `ptr` where you want to test it to be non-empty, exactly the same as with raw pointers.

Comment: Are you just looking for `template<typename AT, typename T> concept cArray=...`? This is enough for you to use for example `cArray<int>` as a constraint.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No I dont want to accept it any unique_ptr<T[]> - only the  specific types of the specific context of the Code.

Comment: Notice that satisfying AT include BT,CT,DT from their definitions.

Comment: typo for b_T: too many `>` in `<a_T<T>>[]>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 possible - I did a fast simplification of my actual code... didn't check if it compiles

Answer (score 3):

You can create a traits and specialize it first:

```
template<typename T> using a_T = std::unique_ptr<T[]>;
template<typename T> using b_T = std::unique_ptr<a_T<T>[]>;
template<typename T> using c_T = std::unique_ptr<b_T<T>[]>;
template<typename T> using d_T = std::unique_ptr<c_T<T>[]>;

template <typename T> struct is_one_of_abcd : std::false_type {};
// specializations
template <typename T> struct is_one_of_abcd<a_T<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_one_of_abcd<b_T<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_one_of_abcd<c_T<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_one_of_abcd<d_T<T>> : std::true_type {};

// And the concept
template<typename T> concept cArrayType = is_one_of_abcd<T>::value;
```

Another option, not directly the same (allow in addition inheritance and conversion), you might have directly:

```
template<typename T> concept cArrayType =
     requires(T t){ []<typename U>(const a_T<U>&){}(t);}
  || requires(T t){ []<typename U>(const b_T<U>&){}(t);}
  || requires(T t){ []<typename U>(const c_T<U>&){}(t);}
  || requires(T t){ []<typename U>(const d_T<U>&){}(t);}
```

checking exact type is also possible but even more verbose.

Comment: I don't know if I like the solution, but it should work. Would be nicer to have all the definitions inside the concept. But lets try this one first :-)